# Interrupting a file upload via Selenium using Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to interrupt a file upload which doesn't seem possible. It seems that nothing gets executed beyond `elem.sendKeys("filename.txt")` until the entire file is uploaded. Further, none of the buttons are clickable although available when checked via Firebug or testing manually.

Automating the file upload and the interrupt by clicking a cancel file upload button (which is clickable when doing the test manually) leads to a test failure with the following exception: `ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with`.

Is there any way I can enforce the interrupt? are there any other means that aids doing the same exact thing?. I'm using **Firefox** for this test.

**HTML**:

```
<div style="padding-left: 40px;">
    <input id="upload" type="file" multiple="" label="File" name="upload[]" size="50">
</div>
```

**Java**:

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id("upload"));
elem.sendKeys("filename.txt");
driver.navigate().refresh();
System.out.println("hi");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have failed to see a point in doing that, but here we go:

I believe u can't stop the `elem.sendKeys()` method in Selenium(which does the actual upload).
Using it on a input text to set a string is the same as actually uploading a file. It's just Selenium trying to set some values on your input.

One way around would be clicking on a cancel upload button you have implemented.

Since you have tried that, this exception `ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with` means exactly the that element **exists** (Selenium have found it on the DOM) but its not visible (the element has some properties like `overflow: hidden` `display:none` etc)
My best guess is that you should work that out and try clicking your button that implements an action of stopping the upload.

Comment: the point is simply to cancel a file upload. The element is visible when doing the test manually. Let's ignore the visibility of the element thing now, you won't be able to close the browser or refresh it or either navigate to another page. It is the fact that the object is being used and you won't be able to do anything further with it until the file is completely uploaded. You won't be able to use the object to do anything.

Comment: It gets stuck on elem.sendKeys()?  
Have you tried setting up a **timeout**?
`new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds)).Until(driver.FindElement(By...));`
I believe it would stop uploading after that time if it stil haven't finished yet. 
You could set this timeout for the WHOLE driver like this:
`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`? 
But remember, any attempt to find elements or wait for requests will use this timeout.

Comment: This won't work either, have you tried it? it will get stuck as well. BTW, that message for element is not visible is because it attempts to access the element after the file got uploaded and which is obviously it was hidden. The element will only be visible during the file upload.

Comment: Didn't try it in this case. The element will be hidden if you hide it (base on the code you shared). Even though you use some framework that automatically hides it, you can set those element properties I mentioned at runtime and before you try to upload the file. Could you share some more code related to that upload?  (e.g., the cancel button, css properties of the button during upload)

Comment: Let's look at this differently. So, let's assume that you are uploading a large file. Refreshing the page should cancel the file upload. In my case, both the refresh and the print out of the word hello will only take place after the file is completely uploaded. Check my modified java code.

Comment: Ran out of ideas, sorry mate.

Comment: Feel free to star it there so that it can get a priority: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7391&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&start=800